# Raise an Event when AJAX Response is recieved

Tags: javascript, ajax, httpresponse

I'm wondering if it is possible to raise an event when any AJAX response is received by my webpage. I'm working in SharePoint so there are a lot of AJAX that Microsoft does to load data into webparts and I'd like to raise an event when my page recieves an AJAX response so I can check if the data has been loaded into the webpart. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of wrapping the global XMLHttpRequest object to log all open()ed URLs:

```
(function(){
  var ajaxOpen=window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open=function(m,u,a){
    this.addEventListener("load", function(){ console.log("ajax loaded", new Date(), m, u, a ); });
    return ajaxOpen.call(this,m,u,a);
  };
}());



$.get("/", function(e){
  console.log(e.length+" bytes fetched");
});
```

when run on this page, something like the following is logged:

```
 ajax loaded Fri May 30 2014 09:56:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) POST /posts/23957352/edit-submit/b4dd7272-6618-4c79-9810-e8ff71122b51 true
```

note that jQuery is used only to show that all ajax calls are affected without modifying a particular library or existing code. with some modification, this can log more details like the data, the response size, the duration the call took, etc.

there is a small RAM cost to doing this, and older browsers might not like having "host objects" messed with, but this style of code can be good for debugging, unit tests, or performance analysis.

EDIT: i found out that ajax does allow more than one event handler using addEventListener() (modern browsers only), so the above code now logs actual responses.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis. This is exactly what I was looking for. The console.log isn't writing in the XMLHttpRequest overide. Is that an issue?

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat: i've tested in in chrome and firefox in the console on this page and it works ok. which browser is giving you issues?

Comment: I just got it working. SP didn't like the script tag in the head. The actual effect I was looking for was achieved with the `$.get`. I am able to fire my own event in that method to initialize my code after the request have been received. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a request to a server is sent, we can perform some actions based on the response.The onreadystatechange event is triggered every time the readyState changes.The readyState property holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest. In the onreadystatechange event, we specify what will happen when the server response is ready to be processed.

When readyState is 4 and status is 200, the response is ready:

Following javascript code will determine if the response is recieved properly or not.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

The readyState property can have following values based on the status of our request:-

0: request not initialized

1: server connection established

2: request received

3: processing request

4: request finished and response is ready

Comment: Do I have to attach the listen to the exact request that is being made or can I listen for all XmlHttpRequest being made by my page?

Comment: Since the request you make will be based on a particular xmlHttp object "xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();" and send request using same object "xmlhttp.send();" , you will also have to receive that request using the same object "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){..}". I dont know if there is a turn around where you can cath all responses at once . But typically the xmlHttp object used to send request will be the one required to track its status.

Comment: yes, you can re-define window.XMLHttpRequest with a logging wrapper that invokes the orig. still, built-in dev tools are more comprehensive, have built in controls, work off-domain, and are already installed in all major browsers.

Comment: Does the `window.XMLHttpRequest` allow me to listen for all requests from the window?

Comment: @dandavis I'm unclear on what exactly you mean. Do you have a reference I can look at to understand this?